# Formatting The Bibliography in LaTeX

Tags: reference, formatting, latex, spacing, bibliography

So I'm writing my bibliography in LaTeX using the following setup. However my references come out in a sort of 'newspaper style'. By this I mean the spacing between the words spreads out for them to fit the line, which leaves massive gaps between some of the names. I just want it to stay together like normal text. My document style is 'report'.

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{}
.
.
.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Answer (score 3):

To avoid big horizontal gaps in it, the bibliography is sometimes preferred to be not justified (while the body of text normally is). One basic way to do this in your setup is:

```latex
\begin{flushleft}
    \begin{thebibliography}{1}
        \bibitem{} ...
        .
        .
        .
    \end{thebibliography}
\end{flushleft}
```